# Resize and Create Thumbnail on Image Upload Django 2 using Pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize an image on upload and also create a thumbnail out of the same resized image. I previously was able to resize the image without issues, however, when I tried adding in the thumbnail feature I was unable to get it working. I have looked at all the other related questions and all of them are either outdated or haven't worked in my case.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    cover_image=models.ImageField(max_length=150, upload_to='project-covers/', default='Default.png', null=True)
    thumbnail=models.ImageField(max_length=150, upload_to='project-thumbnails/', null=True)

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # pdb.set_trace()
        if self.cover_image:
            fname = self.title + '_cover.'
            tname = self.title + '_thumbnail.'
            self.resizeUploadedImage(fname)
            self.createThumbnail(tname)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **

    def resizeUploadedImage(self, fname):
        '''Resize the image being uploaded.'''
        try:
            im = Image.open(self.cover_image)
            if im.width > IMAGE_SIZE[0] or im.heght > IMAGE_SIZE[1]:
                im.resize(IMAGE_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                image_io = BytesIO()
                im.save(image_io, im.format)
                # pdb.set_trace()
                fname = fname + im.format
                self.cover_image.save(fname, ContentFile(image_io.read(), False))
                im.close()
                image_io.close()
        except IOError as e:
            print("Could not resize image for", self.image)
            print(e)

    def createThumbnail(self, fname):
        '''Create thumbnail of the image.'''
        try:
            if self.thumbnail is None:
                im = Image.open(self.cover_image)
                im.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE)
                image_io = BytesIO()
                im.save(image_io, im.format)
                fname = fname + im.format
                self.thumbnail.save(fname, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue(), False))
                im.close()
        except IOError as e:
            print('Could not create a thumbnail for', self.image)
            print(e)
```

Originally I was using the resizeUploadedImage and createThumbnail methods and was successful with the resizing however the thumbnail was always empty on my admin page and db. Before I had 'editable=False' on the thumbnail as I wanted it to be created automatically behind the scenes. I thought that might be preventing the change so I took it out but it didn't change the results.

Then I tried moving both into the save method (as I had previously run into issues when I moved my resize outside the save) but it still doesn't work properly.

I see on several documents that it's best to put the super() call at the end of the save method, but when I do that I get

```
 UNIQUE constraint failed: projects_project.id
```

How can I create a thumbnail out of the cover_image and save it to the thumbnail field?

P.S. While running `./manage.py test projects` it seems to be actually saving files to my disk which I thought wasn't supposed to happen so I assume its some kind of issue with my Pillow code. I end up with '1_cover.PNG', '1Project0_cover.PNG', '1Project1_cover.PNG', '2_cover.PNG' etc, etc, etc counting up to 9 even though my setuptestdata only has 'Project 1'.

P.P.S. I read somewhere that it's better to use Pillow's thumbnail function for resizing as it'll keep the aspect ratio whereas resize won't. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922289/django-pil-save-thumbnail-version-right-when-image-is-uploaded

Comment: `Image.thumbnail()` returns `None` as documented [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) so your `im_thumb` is `None`.

Comment: @ger.s.brett unfortunately that question is in regards to a function view whereas I am using a class view. In addition to that that posters question is in regards to adding an additional image where he needed to add a field. I have a field ready and only need to convert the image and store the value while using a CLASS based view.

Reading through the accepted answer for Python 3 it seems our code is pretty similar, and I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have been able to do this process within the django shell. I used identical code and verified that the im_thumb did have an image of the proper size.

Comment: @Zoneo that's not possible. As I showed you in the link, the `thumbnail()` method creates the thumbnail in place and doesn't return anything (i.e. `im.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE)` actually makes `im` the thumbnail) so you should save `im` at the correct location to get your thumbnail. If you look at the answer given by ger.s.brett you'll also see that: `image.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)` and then `image.save(...)`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I changed both my resize and my thumbnail methods to be im.resize and im.thumbnail however when I ran the django tests it was still saving to my disk and i had a recursion issue in the cover image method. the only way I was able to get past the recursion was to comment out the self.cover_image.save() call, however now the changes arent being saved... Thank you both for all the information, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: what dirkgroten actually means that with the line im_thumb = im.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE) the tumbnail goes into the im object and not into the im_thumb object. The thumbail function of pillow is an in-place modification.

Comment: @ger.s.brett I understand now that the function is self-contained, but I am still having issues of recursion and actually saving the data. With the suggested code in the other answer, I am unable to get past the resize method as the self.cover_image.save() function calls the top of the to resize method (where the image being passed is still not even the right size, causing the recursion to continue.)

Comment: Did you try to replace the line im_thumb.save(image_io, im.format) by im.save(image_io, im.format)?

Comment: @ger.s.brett yes, I removed the new image variable entirely. I have updated my original post to have my current code.

Comment: @ger.s.brett do you have any advice for the issue of recursion I'm having?

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image
def save(self):
    super().save()
    img = Image.open(self.cover_image.path)
    if img.height > 250 or img.width > 250:
    output_size = (250, 250)
    img.thumbnail(output_size)
    img.save(self.cover_image.path)
```

try this way with the size you wanted instead of 250

Comment: `img.thumbnail = output_size` is wrong. Should be `img.thumbnail(output_size)`. Also, you want to save at a different path since you want to create a separate thumbnail file, not modify the original.

Comment: My resize method is working, except for the issue of the test images being saved. Would this resolve that issue? I am not seeing much difference between our code.

Comment: This method saves the image in the specified size