# Wrong thumbnail url returned in Django/DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an application (Django and DRF), by which you can create and view posts. The posts contain an image, and the preview is supposed to only show a thumbnail of the original image, which will be created by the application using Pillow. I mainly followed [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23922289), but changed it to fit my application.

However, the image is saved in `/media/images/`, the thumbnail is saved in `/media/resize/`, the thumbnail-url is saved in the database as `resize/image_thumb.jpg`, but the thumbnail-url in the returned json-object in Postman is the image-url, not the thumbnail-url. Where am I going wrong?

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media/"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('feed/', PostAPIView.as_view(), name='feed_of_posts'),
    path('feed/<int:id>', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='update_delete_posts'),
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(poster = self.request.user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(source='image', required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'pub_date', 'imageDescription', 'poster', 'thumbnail')
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['poster'] =  PosterSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super(PostSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='resize/', editable=False)
    imageDescription = models.TextField()
    ...
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.poster.username} - {str(self.pub_date)}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        **see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011898**

    def make_thumbnail(self):
        **see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011898**
```

I am quite sure, that the problem is not related to the `save()` and `make_thumbnail()` methods in models.py. After creating a post, there is an `image_thumb.jpg` in `media/resize/`. Also in the database, the thumbnail is refered as `resize/image_thumb.jpg`.

However, the json object I get in Postman as a response is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/image.jpg",
    "pub_date": "2023-04-05T08:39:01.827418Z",
    "imageDescription": "API test image upload",
    "poster": "sampleuser"
    "thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/image.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `serializers.py`, `source='image'` tells `thumbnail` serializer field to take value from `image` field of your model. It should be `source='thumbnail'`
or you should be fine removing the field entirely and simply having `'thumbnail'` in your `Meta.fields` and adding it to `Meta.read_only_fields`:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'pub_date', 'imageDescription', 'poster', 'thumbnail']      
        read_only_fields = ['thumbnail']
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this quick response. I had a guess, that it was related to `source='image'`, but I thought this was required, since no thumbnail was provided, when creating the post. Your solution works :)

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly overriding thumbnail path with image path using ***source=***. Try removing this part

```
thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(source='image', required=False)
```

Assuming that thumbnail is not required since you are passing **False**, you can add ***extra_kwargs*** instead:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'pub_date', 'imageDescription', 'poster', 'thumbnail')      
        extra_kwargs = {'thumbnail': {'required': False}}
```

setting **'required' : False** will not be presented when the variable has no value

Comment: this answer worked, as well. But since I can only accept one answer as the solution, I chose the first answer.